# Super Reduced String: Problem with my code - Java

Tags: java, string

My solution for the Super Reduced String problem from HackerRank is giving me problems (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/reduced-string/problem). The example "baab" fails the test case, and I do not understand why. Here is my code:

```
String s = "baab";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i + 1)) {
        s = s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i + 2);
        i = 0;
    }
}
if (s.isEmpty()) {
    return "Empty String";
} else {
    return s;
}
```

The expected result is "Empty String", but the result is "bb".

Through debug statements it seems like the for loop does not run a third time in this specific scenario (once for "ba"ab, second for b"aa"b, and third for "bb"). Why?

Comment: Move the `i++` to else part: `if(..) {...} else i++;`

Comment: Thank you very much! It didn't even cross my mind to omit the i++ in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a few hints

- One loop may not be sufficient
- Keeping a certain `boolean` flag will help you to know when to stop looping
- An algorithm isn't the only way to achieve this, you might want to explore another way of manipulating a `String`

Answer (score -1):

One loop may be sufficient if `StringBuilder` is used which has method `delete(int begin, int end)`

Main point is to make a "step back" when duplicate characters are detected and deleted.

Example solution may look as follows:

```java
static String reduce(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    
    int i = 0;
    
    while (i < sb.length()) {
        int j = i + 1;
        boolean found = false;
        if (j < sb.length() && sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(j)) {
            j++;
            found = true;
        }
        if (found) {
            sb.delete(i, j);
            i --;
            if (i < 0) {
                i = 0;
            }
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    
    if (sb.length() == 0) {
        return "Empty String";
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```